# React Component to Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to convert this to a function component

This is using the React library and I believe I have most of it right.  I think it has something to do with the fetchDraftsTimer function but I am not entirely sure what I am missing.

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component(props) {

    componentDidMount() {

        this.props.fetchDrafts()
        this.props.fetchHistory()

        this.fetchDraftsTimer = setInterval(() => {
            this.props.fetchDrafts();
        }, 120000);
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have done this

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchDrafts;

    props.fetchHistory;

    setInterval(() => {
      props.fetchDrafts;
    }, 120000);

    return () => {
    };
  }, []);


  return null;
}
```

Am I missing something? Apparently both of these are missing some logic. Please help!

Comment: This is a question I was answering for a recruiter. This was the code he gave and said both these components were missing some logic. I tested the component and its returning null so that's not the issue.  I'm assuming some sort of logic is missing in the useEffect hook.

Comment: Your usage of `props.fetchDrafts;` is wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
props.fetchHistory;
props.fetchDrafts;
```

You have to call these functions, exacly like in the class component. You're only supposed to use the above in case you want to pass this function itself down to a child component.

```
props.fetchHistory();
props.fetchDrafts();
```

Comment: Understood! Thank you so much for the insight!